# Orion - cygnus integration

Tags: fiware-orion, fiware-cygnus

We are trying to integrate Orion, Cygnus and Ckan together.
I have followed these steps in order to make this happen:

1. Install and configure Cygnus with the Fiware Ckan info(Cygnus up and running)
2. Login in Ckan and get the API key and configure this in the Cygnus settings
3. Orion steps:

queryUpdate = APPEND data

```
{
"contextElements": [{
    "type": "Room",
    "isPattern": "false",
    "id": "26JanRoom",
    "attributes": [{
        "name": "temperature",
        "type": "float",
        "value": "888"
    }]
}],
"updateAction": "APPEND"
}
```

subscribeContext = subscribe with the entity id created above(our Cygnus host is given as reference "reference": "CYGNUS HOST", )

```
{
"entities": [{
    "type": "Room",
    "isPattern": "false",
    "id": "26JanRoom"
}],
"attributes": ["temperature"],
"reference": "CYGNUS HOST",
"duration": "P1M",
"notifyConditions": [{
    "type": "ONCHANGE",
    "condValues": ["temperature"]
}],
"throttling": "PT5S"
}
```

queryUpdate = UPDATE data

```
{
"contextElements": [{
    "type": "Room",
    "isPattern": "false",
    "id": "26JanRoom",
    "attributes": [{
        "name": "temperature",
        "type": "float",
        "value": "111"
    }]
}],
"updateAction": "UPDATE"
}
```

What we expect is to receive some notifications in the Cygnus side, but there is nothing sent from the Orion (orion.lab.fi-ware.org:1026/)

Could you please help us on this topic?

Thanks kr

Omer Ozdemir

Answer (score 0):

Your are using

```
"condValues": ["pressure"]
```

which means that every time the attribute named `pressure` change, Orion will trigger a notification. However, your update is modifiygin `temperature`.

Please, have a look to [the subscribe context operation section](http://fiware-orion.readthedocs.org/en/develop/user/walkthrough_apiv1/index.html#context-subscriptions) at Orion documentation.

Comment: Hello Fermin, thanks for your comment, actually i was using this guide you've linked and if you check there, its a mistake in the request both temperature and pressure are being used :) 
Well I have changed from pressure to temperature but nothing has happened, I didnt see a notification from the orion in the cygnus logs.. Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: If you refer to use pressure for `condValues` and temperature for `attributes` in the documentation, note that's not a mistake but intentional, to illustrate the differences between both: *"in this case, when Room1 pressure changes, the Room1 temperature value is notified, but not pressure itself"*.

Comment: Regarding the new issue, I'd suggest to post a new question at StackOverlfow in order to deal with it, in order to keep issues (and their potential solutions) separated, please. Thanks!